# create Firebase account without email and password?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to create accounts via Firebase that only create a UID of the user. No password and no email should be requested. The user should be able to delete the app and if he downloads it again, still be able to access his UID and the associated data. In addition, this registration should never expire and the UID of the user should always remain unique and not be overwritten.
Is there a tool in Firebase that can be used to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is known as an anonymous account in Firebase, and you can create one with a single call as shown in documentation for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth), and [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth).

Comment: if I understand it correctly, the anonymous account is not preserved if the user would delete the app.

Comment: Ah, that is indeed correct, I missed your comment about deletion.. There is no anonymous sign-in mechanism that survives deletion in Firebase.